# Windows Jenkins How do i use WORKSPACE system parameter when it has spaces?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins over windows 7 and i encountered strange behavior.
when im trying to copy files to working directory - represented in Jenkins by the system parameter WORKSPACE, for example like in this code:

```
cp -a hpdevops-discovery-demoapp-master/. $WORKSPACE/
```

i get the following:

> - cp -a hpdevops-discovery-demoapp-master/. 'C:\Program' Files '(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins-AutomationFreeStyle-Pipeline-2/'
>
> cp: target '(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins-AutomationFreeStyle-Pipeline-2/' is not a directory

what's happening: the workspace located here: C:\Program' Files '(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins-AutomationFreeStyle-Pipeline-2/

but, because of the space in the path after the word 'Files' its deviding it into 2 and treating the second part - which is just half of the path, as the target path: '(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\jenkins-AutomationFreeStyle-Pipeline-2/'

i used to work with Jenkins on Linux and never had a problem like this when using the WORKSPACE system parameter.
anyone run into this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use double quote wrap it like `"$WORKSPACE"`

Comment: This is insane. Somewhere I see `%WORKSPACE%`, somewhere `${env.WORKSPACE}`, somewhere `%env.WORKSPACE%` and somewhere `$WORKSPACE`. Not to mention this thing with single and double quotes. What is going on here?